# Sonar Multi-Language Test Coverage

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, sonarqube, code-coverage

Using Sonar with language property set to `Java` I was getting Test Coverage.  Now that I have the language property NOT set in order to analyze multiple languages, my test coverage says "No Data".  All of the tests are being run according to the log.  All the src/main code is being analyzed properly and all the tests follow the src/test structure which should be getting picked up according to the documentation.

Sonar Version: 5.1

Build Type: Gradle

Languages used in Project: Java, Groovy

--build.gradle plugins

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"
```

--build.gradle sonarRunner properties

```
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://xxxxx:9000"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://xxxxx:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "sonar"
    }
}
```

Why is my test coverage not showing up when the language property is not specified?